# R data.table subsetting question/error message

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table of the format

```
Time         User    Website    State
2021-01-01   ABC     google      0
2021-01-02   DEF     yahoo       0
2021-01-03   ABC     yahoo       1
```

I want to subset the usert by `State ==1`, so my resulting `data.table` is

```
Time         User    Website    State
2021-01-03   ABC     yahoo       1
```

I tried `newdata <- data[ 'State' == 1 ]` but that results in `The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length(s) (2). Each must be length 0; the same length as there are rows in x (after subsetting if i is provided).`

I also tried `newdata <-data[data[,State==1],]` but ran into the same message there as well. Any thoughts on how I can subset it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In `data.table` you do *not* need to quote your identifiers. You were close and this works as you expected -- but note how I use just `State`, not `'State'`:

```
> data[ State == 1L ]
         Time User Website State
1: 2021-01-03  ABC   yahoo     1
>
```

(and `State == 1` works as well).

Your second approach was wrong the `data.table` idiom is the `data[i, j, by]` and your row conditions must come in the `i` selection as above.